# Comments pagination on author page - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination, comments, author

I have author page (example.com/author/joe) on it **I have listed all author's comments with pagination** but pagination doesn't work after clicking the url - example.com/author/joe/page/2 and page is redirect to index.php.

In other pages it works, Facing problem in this author page only.

Any ideas ?

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$number = get_option('comments_per_page');
$offset = ( $paged - 1 ) * $number;

$count = count( get_comments( array(
    'user_id' => $user_ID,
    'status' => 'approve',
) ) );

$max_total = ceil($count/$number);

$args = array(
    'user_id' => $user_ID,
    'number' => $number,
    'status' => 'approve',
    'offset' => $offset,
    'paged' => $paged
);

$the_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments = $the_query->query( $args );

foreach($comments as $comment){ 
 //code
}


//Pagination
$big = 999999999;

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $max_total,
    'prev_next'=> true,
) );
```

Matt

Comment: Isn't [`paginate_comments_links()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/paginate_comments_links) function what you need?

Comment: It also doesn't work on custom page, like I wrote before it work on other pages, but not on author.php page. I saw somewhere that author slug in this case 'joe' is treated as /page/ and here is problem mb ?

Comment: You can dump $wp_query and see what's going wrong.

Comment: Still not sure, what can be wrong, just on author.php it doesn't work.